# Determinant of a matrix?

Tags: matrices

Can somebody please help me check the solutions to these 2 questions because I do not have the answers to them in my notes:

The determinant of the following matrix:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
4&0&1\\19&1&-3\\7&1&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is

$$0 + 0 +19 - 7-0-(-12) = 24$$
and the determinant of 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0&2&0\\3&0&4\\2&3&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

is

$$0+16+0-0-0-0 = 16$$

Comment: yes, your computations are both correct.

Comment: Tip: [http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=determinant+of+{{4%2C0%2C1}%2C{19%2C1%2C-3}%2C{7%2C1%2C0}}](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=determinant+of+{{4%2C0%2C1}%2C{19%2C1%2C-3}%2C{7%2C1%2C0}})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both answers are correct.  In the future it might be quicker to use [sage](http://www.sagenb.org) or [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) to check things like this.